# Apache ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Using django (I have tried many versions 1.8.7, 1.11.X, 2.0.1) python3.5 amd wsgi 4.5.24 compiled from source making sure that the python path set correctly /usr/bin/python3.5

I have an apache file with several wsgi sript aliases, all of which work except for the django script alias, which only failed when parsing the wsgi.py file because it can't import django. So first is the error from apache:

```
[Tue Jan 02 18:46:32.247088 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2475:tid 139822294771456] [remote 192.168.254.101:2418] mod_wsgi (pid=2475): Target WSGI script '/var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jan 02 18:46:32.247260 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2475:tid 139822294771456] [remote 192.168.254.101:2418] mod_wsgi (pid=2475): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 02 18:46:32.247523 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2475:tid 139822294771456] [remote 192.168.254.101:2418] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 02 18:46:32.247637 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2475:tid 139822294771456] [remote 192.168.254.101:2418]   File "/var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jan 02 18:46:32.247699 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2475:tid 139822294771456] [remote 192.168.254.101:2418]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jan 02 18:46:32.247772 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2475:tid 139822294771456] [remote 192.168.254.101:2418] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

and my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 WSGIScriptAlias /certs /var/www/scripts/CavsCertSearch/CavsCertSearch/certstrip.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias /testcerts /var/www/scripts/CavsCertSearchTest/CavsCertSearch/certstriptest.wsgi
        WSGIScriptAlias /debug /var/www/scripts/debug/debug.wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess protectionprofiles python-path=/var/www/protectionprofiles
        WSGIProcessGroup protectionprofiles
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}  
        WSGIScriptAlias /pp /var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles/wsgi.py process-group=protectionprofiles       

        <Directory /var/www/protectionprofiles/protectionprofiles>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>

        Alias /static/  /var/www/protectionprofiles/static/
        <Directory /var/www/protectionprofiles/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Its just the last Script alias that is failing for protection profiles. django was installed with pip3, which is how i can specify versions. I do not need to use a virtual envirnment, which I still don't really understand that. but when I use python on the interpreter I can say

```
import django
```

and it works fine. Any hints is to how to get the django package to run under mod_wsgi would be helpful, sense I have followed all the tutorials and none of them seem to work. Thank you in advance.

wanted to add some version info. running the example of:
http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use
yielded:

```
sys.version = '3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) \n[GCC 6.3.0 20170406]'
sys.prefix = '/usr'
sys.path = ['/var/www/protectionprofiles', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: Have you verified what Python installation/version mod_wsgi is built for? It may be different to where you have installed Django. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: So i got the outputs but im not really sure how to use that to validate my install. So the version matched. the prefix is the /usr, but  my python exe is under /usr/bin/python3, is that a problem? because it finds the python executable?

Comment: From the command line interpreter, if you do ``import django; django.__file__``, what do you get?

Comment: /home/svn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py

Comment: You have installed your Python package in your user specific site-packages directory and not in the global Python installation. When using mod_wsgi that isn't going to be used as mod_wsgi doesn't run as you but the Apache user. You would be better off to learn about virtual environments at this point. Alternatively uninstall Django and reinstall it but in your global Python installation.

Comment: ok that was it. I just needed to install it globally thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction! I specifically want my package to be global because I was all apps to be using the same packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Graham helped me figure out was that appareantly in python there is a local and global versions of the package manager. So all I need to do was

```
pip3 uninstall django
sudo -H pip3 install django==1.11.9
```

Comment: For me, when I run this command I get the error `no module named pip._internal`. Even though pip is installed.